# Blazor Server Mode Dispose Timer

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Consider a sample `Blazor` application created under `.NET 8` (as of now `rc1`) with the following command: `dotnet new blazor --use-server`

Add a sample page with this content:

```
@page "/"
@using System.Timers 
@implements IDisposable 
@attribute [RenderModeServer]

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle> 

@code {
    Timer? _timer; 
    
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized");
        _timer = new Timer(); 
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true; 

    }  

    private void OnElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Timer:Elapsed {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    } 
    
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose"); 
        _timer?.Dispose();  
    }  
}
```

When pressing F5 repeatedly in the browser with the page open, `Dispose` is not called immediatelly. This causes multiple `Timer` objects being run at the same time.
`Dispose` is being called eventually after a certain time (2-3 minutes?), but I am not too fond of this behaviour. I can essentially `DDOS` myself by refreshing the page.
Is there any way I can immediatelly cleanup the `Timer` with Blazor when the page is refreshed or navigated away?

Comment: Nope not encountering same case as you described. Try monitoring using Debug.Print instead of CW.

Comment: You are using a pre-release version.  If you believe you've found an issue, report your findings on the GitHub site - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues .  If you're writing a real app use Net7.

Answer (score 0):

In Blazor, the IDisposable interface is typically used to clean up resources when a component is removed from the component tree, not when the page is refreshed. The Dispose method is called when a component is being disposed of by Blazor, which only happens when it is removed from the component tree as mentioned. This occurs when you navigate away from a page or when the component itself is removed for other reasons.
When you refresh a Blazor page, the page and its components are not being disposed of in the same way as when you navigate away. Instead, the page typically is reloaded, and the components on that page are recreated. This means that the dispose mthod of a component is not automatically called when you refresh the page because the components are not being removed and disposed.

If you want to perform specific cleanup when the page is refreshed, you'll need to handle this differently.

You can use JavaScript interop to hook into the browser's beforeunload event and perform cleanup tasks when the user refreshes the page. This approach allows you to execute JavaScript code before the page is refreshed

```js
@page "/"
@using System.Timers
@implements IDisposable
@attribute [RenderModeServer]

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function () {
        // Call a C# method to trigger resource cleanup
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('YourAssemblyName', 'DisposeComponent');
    });
</script>

@code {
    Timer? _timer;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnInitialized");
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += OnElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void OnElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Timer:Elapsed {DateTime.Now.ToString()}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    // C# method to be invoked from JavaScript
    [JSInvokable]
    public void DisposeComponent()
    {
        // Dispose of resources
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct, browser events such as `beforeunload` are designed to automatically trigger the component's disposal. Here's a bug report for that specifically https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5633

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks for that info! :)